Improving execution time of analytical ray tracing algorithm
Background
I've written a Python class that is designed to compute the time taken for a ray of light to propagate between two points (init_point and term_point) in a complex medium (modeled using the parameters medium_model = [A, B, C]).
To compute this light transit time, we need two things:

The aforementioned initial and terminal points.
The angle (launch_angle) that the light ray makes with the x-axis at the initial point.

I have an expression for the z-coordinate of the ray in terms of the x and y coordinates (which we treat as one "x"-coordinate (x = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)), the launch_angle, and the initial and terminal points, so we can determine the latter by simply optimizing the difference between the known terminal z-coordinate and what we get for various values of launch_angle.

Code
from dataclasses import dataclass
import warnings
import numpy as np

# Suppress warnings (sometimes there is overflow in _calculate_z_coord, etc.)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)

@dataclass
class RayTracer:
    medium_model: np.ndarray
    SPEED_OF_LIGHT = 299792458  # Speed of light in m/s

    def _calculate_z_coord(self, x: np.ndarray, launch_angle: np.ndarray, x0: np.ndarray, z0: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Calculate the z-coordinate based on launch angle and other parameters."""
        A, B, C = self.medium_model

        exp_Cz0 = np.exp(C * z0)
        cos_launch_angle = np.cos(launch_angle)
        beta = (A - B * exp_Cz0) * cos_launch_angle
        
        sqrt_A2_beta2 = np.sqrt(A**2 - beta**2)
        K = C * sqrt_A2_beta2 / beta

        term1 = A**2 - beta**2
        term2 = A * B * exp_Cz0
        sqrt_term = np.sqrt(term1 + 2 * term2 + B**2 * exp_Cz0**2)

        # Precompute for efficiency
        log_arg = term1 + term2 + sqrt_A2_beta2 * sqrt_term
        t = (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C * x0 - beta * C * z0 + beta * np.log(log_arg)) / (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C)

        exp_Kx = np.exp(K * x)
        exp_Kt = np.exp(K * t)
        log_term_num = 2 * term1 * np.exp(K * (t + x))
        log_term_den = beta**2 * B**2 * exp_Kx**2 - 2 * A * B * exp_Kt + exp_Kt**2
        log_term = log_term_num / log_term_den

        return (1 / C) * np.log(log_term)

    def _find_launch_angle(self, init_points: np.ndarray, term_points: np.ndarray, num_steps: int = 1000) -> np.ndarray:
        """Find the optimal launch angle."""
        x0 = np.hypot(init_points[:, 0], init_points[:, 1])
        x1 = np.hypot(term_points[:, 0], term_points[:, 1])
        
        # Coarse search with a fine search
        launch_angles = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num_steps)

        # Precompute z_coords for all launch angles
        z_coords = self._calculate_z_coord(x1[:, np.newaxis], launch_angles, x0[:, np.newaxis], init_points[:, 2, np.newaxis])

        term_z = term_points[:, 2][:, np.newaxis]
        objective_values = (z_coords - term_z)**2

        # Find the best angles
        best_indices = np.nanargmin(objective_values, axis=1)
        best_angles = launch_angles[best_indices]

        return best_angles

    def transit_time(self, init_points: np.ndarray, term_points: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Calculate the transit time."""
        A, B, C = self.medium_model

        # Vectorized launch angle search
        launch_angles = self._find_launch_angle(init_points, term_points)

        exp_Cz_init = np.exp(C * init_points[:, 2])
        beta = np.abs((A - B * exp_Cz_init) * np.cos(launch_angles))
        sqrt_A2_beta2 = np.sqrt(A**2 - beta**2)
        K = C * sqrt_A2_beta2 / beta

        def time_expression(z: np.ndarray, beta: np.ndarray, K: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
            exp_Cz = np.exp(C * z)
            t = np.sqrt((A + B * exp_Cz - beta) / (A + B * exp_Cz + beta))
            alpha = np.sqrt((A - beta) / (A + beta))
            log_expr = np.log(np.abs((t - alpha) / (t + alpha)))
            return A * np.sqrt((C**2 + K**2) / (C**2 * K**2)) * log_expr

        time_diff = time_expression(term_points[:, 2], beta, K) - time_expression(init_points[:, 2], beta, K)

        return time_diff / self.SPEED_OF_LIGHT

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ray_tracer = RayTracer(np.array([1.78, 0.454, 0.0132]))

    # Generate random init_points and term_points
    num_points = 100000
    init_points = np.random.uniform(low=-50, high=50, size=(num_points, 3))
    term_points = np.random.uniform(low=-50, high=50, size=(num_points, 3))

    # I'm including a simple but rough measure of the execution time using `time` here, for your reference. 
    import time

    start_time = time.time()
    transit_times = ray_tracer.transit_time(init_points, term_points)
    end_time = time.time()

    # Print results
    print("Transit times:", transit_times)
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end_time - start_time:.6f} seconds")

The code is vectorized. Initializing a RayTracer is done as follows:
my_ray_tracer = RayTracer(np.array([A, B, C]))

The transit_time() function is vectorized, and takes an array of initial and terminal points, e.g.:
init_points = np.random.uniform(low=-50, high=50, size=(num_points, 3))
term_points = np.random.uniform(low=-50, high=50, size=(num_points, 3))

transit_times = ray_tracer.transit_time(init_points, term_points)


My "Problem"
I in some applications would like to be able to quickly compute the propagation time for thousands, tens of thousands, or even hundreds of thousands of rays. While this code is quite fast, it is not yet quite fast enough for some of my applications. I've employed all of the tricks that I'm familiar with (e.g. vectorization), and have cut the average execution time down significantly, but still not significantly enough that it is useful for what I need it to be.
My requirements are as follows:

I am not terribly concerned with memory efficiency, only the execution time of transit_time().
I am contributing this to a code base whose dependencies are only NumPy and SciPy. I cannot make use of any additional external libraries.

How can I further improve the execution time of this code?

numba could probably optimize some of your expressions, that's what it was created for. It comes highly recommended, but I personally couldn't ever get much value from it in practice, since it lags behind and demands some outdated version of numpy every time I tried.
Many of your expressions involve multiple vector terms, which create temporary vectors for each binary operator. E.g. np.sqrt(A**2 - beta**2) creates 3 temporary vectors, the last of which is passed into np.sqrt, which creates the 4th result vector.
You could try doing in-place vector modifications to avoid creation of temporary vectors for each binary operator, and explicitly specify output vectors for numpy operators to avoid allocation of new vectors. That makes the code much faster, and much less maintainable. But the binary vector operators are still rather sub-optimal in terms of memory allocations, number of loads and stores, and loops.
The ultimate performance of your vector calculations can be achieved by coding these calculations as element-wise with hand coded loops in Cython or C++.
E.g. np.sqrt(A**2 - beta**2) does one vector allocation and loop to calculate A**2 invoking std::pow function for each element, same for beta**2, another allocation and loop for the difference of these temporary vectors and another allocation and loop for np.sqrt.
Using Cython or C++, np.sqrt(A**2 - beta**2) can be calculated with one memory allocation for the result and one loop, loading elements of both A and beta in each iteration, squaring them with simple multiplication rather than calling std::pow, taking the difference and square root and storing the result.
In Cython it would have to call std::sqrt, but in C++ it can invoke the square root CPU instruction, so that this entire expression is calculated in one loop with no calls to library functions. Which would result in orders of magnitude faster calculations for such expressions. More than that, in C++ this one loop can use SIMD instructions to at least quadruple its throughput. numpy does that as well, but it cannot possibly calculate this entire expression in one loop with SIMD and no library calls or extra memory allocations, and bottlenecks on loads and stores.
Loads and stores missing CPU caches are often the main bottleneck in calculations. Doing as many as possible calculations per one load and store is most optimal: it eliminates unnecessary CPU data cache thrashing, and gives more time to hardware to prefetch arrays into CPU data cache for you before the next load or store.

My personal approach for calculating such vector expressions with multiple terms is creating a Cython wrapper function that accepts input arrays as contiguous memory views, allocates an array for the result, and passes plain pointers to the arrays and the length to a C++ function that does the calculation of the expression. The C++ function can unleash SIMD vector intrinsincs, restricted pointers, branching hints, etc. to calculate it in one loop fastest. But just one plain element-wise C++ loop to do the calculation, minimizing the number of loads and stores, is often good enough.

using in-place operations is spot-on, since this code is mostly memory-bandwidth bound, in-place operations will double its performance (because it will hit half the memory footprint), the maintainability part is why i personally never used that in any large-scale project.

Good answer and +1 for proposing Cython here. "in C++ this one loop can use SIMD instructions to at least quadruple its throughput" This is more complex not to mention it depends of the target SIMD instruction set and the CPU architecture (eg. SSE, AVX, AVX-512, or even SVE, etc.). Some instruction can double-pumped if not all on some architecture. Let's say simply "significantly faster".

Regarding Cython and C++, one need to be careful about compilation flags and packaging. Numpy can automatically select the best instruction set to use, eg. AVX on CPU supporting it (even possibly AVX-512) or SSE for ones that does not. This is good for raw performance though there are many overhead to consider (emphasized in your answer). The thing is native code are compiled for generic CPUs by default so only SSE2 is supported. One can explicitly target AVX2 but then it will not run on machine supporting only AVX1 or SSE (same for AVX1 vs SSE, or even AVX-512 vs AVX2).

Supporting multiple target can AFAIK be quite cumbersome. One can compile multiple version of the compiled package and use the good one at runtime though this is not trivial for beginners (especially since one need to consider the many SSE version, the 2 AVX ones, the many AVX-512 ones, and possibly ones of other architecture like Neon, SVE, VSX, etc.). IDK if there are packagers or methods to do that automatically (since it is a general problem for compiled Python modules).

@JérômeRichard You are quite right with all these concerns. My advice comes from HPC domain where target CPU architecture and model is known ahead and the code is targeted and tuned precisely for that to minimize compute costs. Portability always has extra costs, which are expended only if required. Using a non-portable CPU instruction that reduces run-time/compute-bill by 1% trumps portability.

I know that you don't want to install dependencies, but I guess that you can install ones for your own development needs. In such a case, line_profiler can help you. See https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/.
It appears that, when I profile transit_time that way, 99% of time is spent on _find_launch_angle.
Same game -> 94% of time spent on _calculate_z_coord:

19.8% t = (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C * x0 - beta * C * z0 + beta * np.log(log_arg)) / (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C)
11% log_term_num = 2 * term1 * np.exp(K * (t + x))
12% log_term_den = beta**2 * B**2 * exp_Kx**2 - 2 * A * B * exp_Kt + exp_Kt**2

I always consider that better thinking is more powerful that any technological change. But, well, optimizing numpy calculations is very difficult.
Again, I know that you are not supposed to add additional dependencies, but I'm pretty sure that you can argue on one pip install and one additional line of code... Let's give it a try...
I can see that _calculate_z_coord is not using self, except for passing medium_model. So, I've adapted a bit to make it a top level function instead of a method:
def _calculate_z_coord(medium_model: np.array, x: np.ndarray, launch_angle: np.ndarray, x0: np.ndarray, z0: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Calculate the z-coordinate based on launch angle and other parameters."""
    A, B, C = medium_model
    ...

class RayTracer:
    def _func_launch_angle(...):
        ...
        z_coords = _calculate_z_coord(self.medium_model, x1[:, np.newaxis], launch_angles, x0[:, np.newaxis], init_points[:, 2, np.newaxis])
        ...

And now the optimization in itself: using numba for just-in-time compilation and other automated optimizations:
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=False, fastmath=True)
def _calculate_z_coord(medium_model: np.array, x: np.ndarray, launch_angle: np.ndarray, x0: np.ndarray, z0: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Calculate the z-coordinate based on launch angle and other parameters."""

Impact? Move from 16 seconds execution time to 10 seconds ... only by transforming a method to a function and decorating it.
Why this preliminary transormation? Because numba works well with numpy arrays and @numba.jitclass is still experimental...
Coming back to this dependencies constraint, it's natural that you use numpyfor such intensive computations. I think that numba can become natural too.
Unfortunately, as you might guess in the proposal, I've tried with numba parallelization, but it din't worked. You can try to set parallel=True and debug it if you want to have additional performance increase, but I'm not sure if that's making sense.
Please have a look at https://numba.pydata.org.
Another option where you can give a try is moving to massively parallel GPU enabled libraries like tensorflow or pytorch. They're mainly used for AI, but because ... AI it doing a lots of tensor computation ... like RayTracing. So, I guess that you will find miracles there ... after full redesign of your algorithm. But in that case, the dependency story will be more complex...

"I'm pretty sure that you can argue on one pip install and one additional line of code" While it is often just one line for a user, adding new dependencies can have strong implications. For example, Numba may not build on some machines or with some package managers. I personally have found issues with uv or on a non-standard machines. Numba can also limit the version of Numpy uses (for example Numpy 1.x while the user may need Numpy 2.0 for sake of performance). Numba is also pretty big and embedded LLVM which is far from being cheap.

Numba also adds a compilation time which can sometimes be an issue (eg. for distributed codes running on supercomputers or even in some cases with multiprocessing). parallel=True makes it bigger and might be a problem regarding the calling code. In practice, Numba is great for prototyping but not so for packaged libraries. I think it would be better to simply use native code or Cython here. This does not add dependencies but require a compilation step when the package is built. This also avoid using experimental features and avoid an additional heavy dependency.

A few ideas I found that achieve about a 20% speedup, that avoid incorporating any new libraries.
First, this line:
log_term_num = 2 * term1 * np.exp(K * (t + x))

can be rewritten as
log_term_num = 2 * term1 * exp_Kx * exp_Kt

which saves one exponent operation.
The second idea concerns this line.
t = (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C * x0 - beta * C * z0 + beta * np.log(log_arg)) / (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C)

This can be simplified via the following algebra
t = (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C * x0 - beta * C * z0 + beta * np.log(log_arg)) / (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C)
# divide top and bottom by beta
t = (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C / beta * x0 - C * z0 + np.log(log_arg)) / (sqrt_A2_beta2 * C / beta)
# replace sqrt_A2_beta2 * C / beta with K
t = (K * x0 - C * z0 + np.log(log_arg)) / K
# Factor K * x0 term out
t = x0 + (- C * z0 + np.log(log_arg)) / K

So this line is equivalent to
t = x0 + (- C * z0 + np.log(log_arg)) / K

I had trouble checking if this was equivalent to the original - I think this line may be numerically unstable. YMMV.

You can add multithreading (builtin to python), numpy drops the GIL, so you do get some speedup from it, numpy apps usually hit the memory bandwidth limit before the computation limit of the cores, so don't expect too much of a speedup. (at least don't expect complete concurrency)
    start_time = time.time()
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count
    with ThreadPool(cpu_count()) as pool:
        transit_times = np.hstack(pool.starmap(ray_tracer.transit_time,
                                     zip(np.array_split(init_points, cpu_count()),
                                     np.array_split(term_points,cpu_count()))))
    end_time = time.time()

on this 4 core machine it went from 15.893981 seconds to 9.272425 seconds, but the actual benefit depends on both the number of cores and the memory bandwidth, (in this case i know the ratio is exactly how much my RAM bandwidth is larger than my single core bandwidth so i know this hits the memory bandwidth, not the computation limit).
Playing with the size of each chunk also helps but its effect depends on the CPU cache size, for example on this machine using a 100 element chunks made the best speedup to 4.067283 seconds (down from 15 seconds), but rerun the same code on a computer with a different cache size and a different chunk size will be better. I tried it on another machine and the optimum was at 50 elements, so it will need some experimentation, better let the user control it (along with the number of threads)
    chunk_size = 100
    with ThreadPool(cpu_count()) as pool:
        transit_times = np.hstack(pool.starmap(ray_tracer.transit_time,
                                               zip(np.array_split(init_points, len(init_points)/chunk_size),
                                                   np.array_split(term_points, len(term_points)/chunk_size))))

As for how you can get past the memory bandwidth limit (other than buying more RAM sticks) ... there is numba which you can use to get around how slow the python interpreter is, so you can remove vectorization (because vectorization is the reason you are hitting the memory bandwidth limit) and instead let the compiler decide which operations to vectorize, but if you really need to squeeze the most performance out of this then you should consider writing a C/C++ extension to do the computations. (PyBind11 + Eigen will make this a lot easier than you think)

As pointed in Maxim Egorushkin answer, inplace operations can help, this is an example of how one function will be rewritten in-place, it is 30% faster but 100% less maintainable, using the above multithreading it is down to 3 seconds (down from 15 seconds)
    def _calculate_z_coord(self, x: np.ndarray, launch_angle: np.ndarray, x0: np.ndarray, z0: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Calculate the z-coordinate based on launch angle and other parameters."""
        A, B, C = self.medium_model

        Cmz0 = C * z0
        exp_Cz0 = np.exp(Cmz0,out=Cmz0)
        del Cmz0

        cos_launch_angle = np.cos(launch_angle)
        beta = (A - B * exp_Cz0) * cos_launch_angle

        AsqrmBetasqr = A ** 2 - beta ** 2
        sqrt_A2_beta2 = np.sqrt(AsqrmBetasqr,out=AsqrmBetasqr)
        del AsqrmBetasqr

        Cmsqrt_A2_beta2 = C * sqrt_A2_beta2
        K = np.divide(Cmsqrt_A2_beta2,beta, out=Cmsqrt_A2_beta2)
        del Cmsqrt_A2_beta2

        term1 = A ** 2 - beta ** 2
        term2 = A * B * exp_Cz0
        expr_term12 = term1 + 2 * term2 + B ** 2 * exp_Cz0 ** 2
        sqrt_term = np.sqrt(expr_term12, out=expr_term12)
        del expr_term12

        # Precompute for efficiency
        log_arg = term1 + term2 + sqrt_A2_beta2 * sqrt_term
        t = x0 + (- C * z0 + np.log(log_arg, out=log_arg)) / K

        Kx = K * x
        exp_Kx = np.exp(Kx, out=Kx)
        del Kx

        Kt = K * t
        exp_Kt = np.exp(Kt, out=Kt)
        del Kt

        temp = term1
        del term1
        temp *= 2
        temp *= exp_Kx
        temp *= exp_Kt
        log_term_num = temp

        exp_kt_squared = exp_Kt ** 2
        temp = exp_Kt
        del exp_Kt
        temp *= 2 * A * B
        term2 = temp
        del temp

        temp = exp_Kx
        del exp_Kx
        temp **= 2
        temp *= B**2
        temp2 = beta
        del beta
        temp2 **=2
        temp *= temp2
        del temp2
        term1 = temp
        del temp

        log_term_den = np.add(np.subtract(term1,term2,out=term1),exp_kt_squared, out=term1)
        del term1
        log_term = np.divide(log_term_num, log_term_den, out=log_term_den)
        del log_term_den

        return np.multiply(1/C,np.log(log_term,out=log_term),out=log_term)

